# Why am i getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Answers));
Collections.shuffle(al);
char answer=(char) (al.indexOf(right)+65);
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
    al.set(i, ((char)(i+65))+")"+al.get(i));
}
String[] s=al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
int n = s.length+1;
String[] ret = new String[n];
System.arraycopy(s,0,ret,1,n);
ret[0]=answer+"";
return ret;
```

I expected it to work and not crash but i am getting this instead:"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" on this line:

```
System.arraycopy(s,0,ret,1,n);
```

I don't know why and any help is welcome.

Comment: have you checked it with a debugger to see what line is generating your exception?

Comment: Sorry, too much magic operations in your code. Try looking into `s`'s ans `ret`'s length before copying.

Comment: The length argument is the size of the destination array, which is 1 greater than the size of the source array. See the javadoc for `arrayCopy()`, it very clearly explains possible error conditions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanted

```
System.arraycopy(s, 0, ret, 1, s.length);
```

Currently, you're trying to copy `n` (which equals `s.length + 1`) elements out of `s`.

Comment: you mean `s.length -1` ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: No, I don't mean that.